# package statement marked as "unused import"

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a scala class which defines his package like this

`package exporters`

The class is under the following directory structure:

`src/main/scala/exporters/ExporterManager.scala`

When compiling the project with `sbt`, I get the following warning:

```
[warn] /scala/export/src/main/scala/exporters/ExporterManager.scala:1:Unused import
[warn] package exporters
[warn] ^
[warn] one warning found
```

How can I fix this warning?

EDIT:

Here is an extract of the class code:

```
package exporters

import java.util.Date
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger

import akka.actor.SupervisorStrategy.Stop
import akka.actor._
import com.amazonaws.services.cloudwatch.model.{StandardUnit, MetricDatum, PutMetricDataRequest}
...

import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.pickling.Defaults._
import scala.pickling.json._
import scala.util.Try

class ExporterManager extends Actor with ActorJsonLogging {
    def receive = {
        ....
    }

    ...
}
```

The missing imports are for our classes but nothing special. It is a basic Akka actor.

Comment: Can you post the class code? Or at least the first few lines? Are there any import statements?

Comment: Try to clean project before compilation.

Comment: Even if we clean compile, the warning appears on some classes always the same ones.

Answer (score 5):

In my case I was using the Play Framework. I was using the macros to create play.api.libs.json.Reads (play.api.libs.json.Json.reads)

The warnings disappeared once I replaced the macro with code to manually create the Reads.

Comment: We think it is caused by https://github.com/scala/pickling which uses macros. You may be right but could not find any fix to the warning.

Answer (score 3):

Not a solution, but a workaround, in case your issue is related to Play's Json macros. Turns out the bug is associated with the `reads` macro, but not in the `format` macro, so we can take advantage of the fact that `Format[X]` extends `Reads[X]`:

```
implicit val noteReads: Reads[Note] = Json.format[Note]
```